# Why 'where' statement seems to filter expected rows in SAS proc SQL?

Tags: sql, sas

I full joined 2 tables first and then full joined a 3rd table, now I got 1000 more rows in the result. But when I added a where statement following the join process I can only get 200 more rows and it seems that some expected rows were filtered. I don't know what I've done wrong.

```
proc sql;
    create table ECG.RECON as 
    select a.SUBJID as SUBJID_004 , 
        a.VISIT as VISIT_004, 
        input(a.EGDAT, yymmdd10.) as EGDAT_004 , 
        ...
        b.SUBJID as SUBJID_001 , 
        ...
        c.DSDECOD 
    from 
    SOURCE.A a full join SOURCE.B b on 
            (a.SUBJID = b.SUBJID and a.VISIT = b.VISIT )
    full join SOURCE.C as c on b.SUBJID = c.SUBJID
    where c.EPOCH = "SCR" and c.DSDECOD ne "FAILURE" and a.TEST = "Inter";
quit;
```

Comment: why are you using full join and what are trying to achieve by that?

Comment: Move the WHERE clause conditions to the ON clause to get true FULL JOIN result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your where clause is causing empty rows to be filtered. Consider a simplified schema:

**TableA**

```
Col1    Col2
----------------
1        A
2        B
```

**TableB**

```
Col1    Col2
----------------
1        X
3        Y
```

And a simple full join with no filter:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableA AS A
        FULL JOIN TableB AS B
            ON A.Col1 = B.Col1
```

Which will return

```
A.Col1   A.Col2     B.Col1    B.Col2
---------------------------------------
1        A          1           X
2        B          NULL        NULL
NULL    NULL        3           Y
```

Now, if you apply a filter to anything from A, e.g. `WHERE A.Col1 = 1`, you'll get rid of the 2nd Row (probably as intended) since `2 <> 1`, but you'll also remove the 3rd row, since `A.Col` is `NULL`, and `NULL <> 1`. As you have removed all rows with no matching record in `TableA` you have effectively turned your full join into a left join. If you then apply a further predicate on `TableB`, your left join becomes an inner join.

With Full joins, I find the easiest solution is to apply your filters **before** the join by using subqueries, e.g.:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE Col1 = 1) AS A
        FULL JOIN TableB AS B
            ON A.Col1 = B.Col1;
```

Which removes the 2nd row, but still retains the 3rd row from the previous results:

```
A.Col1   A.Col2     B.Col1    B.Col2
---------------------------------------
1        A          1           X
NULL    NULL        3           Y
```

You can also use `OR`, but the more predicates you have the more convoluted this can get, e.g.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableA AS A
        FULL JOIN TableB AS B
            ON A.Col1 = B.Col1
WHERE   (Col1 = 1 OR A.Col1 IS NULL);
```

Comment: Note that SAS does NOT use the tri-level logic that some SQL implementations use.  You can test if missing (aka NULL) is equal to missing. And missing values are smaller than any actual number.

Comment: Thanks @Tom, I was not aware of that (as I have never actually used SAS). I have removed the part about null not being equal to anything, not even null, as it does not apply.